# Any advantage or Disadvantage Protractor Vs Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am currently working on the WebApp which has Lot of Angular js... We started with Selenium WebDriver and the scripts works well scratch codes... But I am suggested that we need to use protractor instead of Selenium WebDriver. As far as both do the same job for me. The ONLY difference I found is that I don't want to wait explicitly to load the webpage..

Is there any other advantage or disadvantage in Protractor Vs Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: Huge disadvantage is that Selenium sounds better.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened because it is a valid question with a good factual answer.

Comment: Reopen vote given. It's not an opinion based question. We can compare these tools based on clear facts, not our opinions, which will help people to pick the right tool for their specific requirements.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hi we can have a discussion over it but as far as selenium vs protractor goes:

**SELENIUM**

1. Works great even if it's angular JS website, only we have to deal with synchronization issue. If you can handle then no disadvantage.
2. Selenium is very rich in automation, i.e, it's in the market for years and very much evolved and its API is almost stable.
3. It's in fact a defacto tool in the open source market for browser automation.
4. You can work with selenium in almost every popular language.

**PROTRACTOR**

1. Is marketed as angular based automation tool. But when you would look at its core it's wrapper for webdriver JS. Hence it does not uncover any new vertical in browser automation.
2. Yes it has certain advantage in case of angular specific locator strategy. It provides more option to work with Angular directives (i.e angular specific locator strategy).
3. It's only available for only one client (language) i.e for JavaScript only. So to work with it you must know JavaScript.
4. New in the market although its based on the webdriverJs.

So it totally depends upon your project requirement and team knowledge which tool you want to use. It will not be good to say which has what advantage over other. Both tools are here to help us and make browser automation flawless. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is Protractor, the Wrapper of Selenium WebDriver? I will get the benefit of Selenium Webdriver and Protractor's own feature???

Comment: yes Protractor is wrapper for Webdriverjs so you get each and every faeture of webdriverjs in protractor + protractor's own feature

Comment: please go through this link for better understanding of protractor http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/getting-started