# What is the difference between Proctractor and Selenium?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am in the stage to find out what is [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Its website looks very old. [Here](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide) is a nodejs version of it.

I also found a good in browser testing solution [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/).

Are they designed to do the same thing? Which one should I use? Why Selenium website is so old, out of favor?

Comment: Protractor *uses* selenium...

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do you find out?

Comment: ...it says so on the front page of their website?

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178187/for-e2e-testing-which-is-better-selenium-or-protractor-for-following-web-stack, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931204/any-advantage-or-disadvantage-protractor-vs-selenium etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tools you mention above like protractor, nightwatch are all based on [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium). If you are looking for a nodejs based solutions you can either directly use [WebDriverJS](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) (popularly known as selenium) or use many other frameworks which are developed on top of it. Every framework below offers unique features, you need to pick what works best for you. The basic advantage of using framworks is that they do most of the heavy lifting for you, that way your code is small and maintainable. UI testing is hard, the smaller the code you have the easier it is to maintain

- [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) (good support if your app is angular)
- [nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide)
- [nemo](https://github.com/paypal/nemo)
- [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io/)
- [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd)